# Validating multiple image uploads on laravel form fails

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I've built a basic application in Laravel here - however I have two models namely an article and photo model. An Article can have many photos and so I have set up my form so that you can dynamically via javascript add multiple file inputs. The problem here is that if there are no validation errors the form works just swell - however if there is a validation error - I get this scary error message that says

```
 htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: D:\wamp\www\one1\one1info-revamped\app\views\administration\articles\create.blade.php)
```

Here is the code of my store method in the controller:

```
public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::except('photos', 'captions');
        $validation = Validator::make($input, Article::$rules);
        $photos = Input::file('photos');
        $captions = Input::file('captions');

        if ($validation->passes() ){


            $article = $this->article->create($input);

            foreach($photos as $ii => $one_photo){
                $photo = new Photo();
                $name = $article->title . '-' . $ii;

                $photo->create_n_upload($one_photo, array(  'name'=>$name, 
                                                            'caption'=>$captions[$ii], 
                                                        'imageable_type'=>'Article', 
                                                        'imageable_id'=>$article->id ));
            }

            return Redirect::route('admin.articles.index');
        }



        return Redirect::route('admin.articles.create')
            ->withInput()->withErrors($validation);

    }
```

I don't really know where am I getting this wrong here - also here is my article model:

```
class Article extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();


  public function photos()
  {
      return $this->morphMany('Photo', 'imageable');
  }

    public static $rules = array(
        'title' => 'required',
        'author' => 'required',
        'caption' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
    'section_id'=>'required',
    'dated'=>'',
        'is_published' => 'required',
        'created_by' => ''
    );
}
```

You can see I haven't put any rules yet for the images - however just including them within the form has started to cause this error. It only happens if the validation fails - if everything is entered as required - it goes smoothly however I need to make sure that error handling is working fine here.

Here is what the upload file looks like on my form:

```
  <li>
        {{ Form::label('images', 'Images:') }}
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link-add-image" class="btn btn-small">ADD IMAGE</a>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <ul id="image-upload-holder">
            <li>      
               <div class="well">
                 <input name="photos[]" type="file" />
                 {{ Form::text('captions[]') }}
                 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-small lnk-remove-image"><i class="icon-cross"/></a>
               </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
```

Comment: the error message is straight forward. on your error output, you are using `htmlentity` or `e()` over an array. the problem is on error output, not in the form.

Comment: Ok so what exactly do I do to get this fixed here? I think I'm missing something but can't actually put my finger on it

Comment: Here check my gist for the view file : https://gist.github.com/maliakmal/8970397